# $_GET URL from ?url=http://google.com

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm making a redirect script for my site, I use htaccess to rewrite the URL so it looks nicer.

eg. `http://localhost/r/http://google.com` is the URL, but when I printing the value it shows up like this `http:/google.com`.
One `/` is missing, how can I fix that?

**Edit:**
Rewrite rule:
`RewriteRule ^r/(.*)/$ /system/offsite/redirect/index.php?url=$1 [L]`

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Maybe you should show us your rewrite rules.

Comment: urlencode() / urldecode() may fix that problem

Comment: ^r/(.*)/$ expects a / at the end of the address tobe redirected, like http://localhost/r/http://google.com// so removing it may fix your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is due to Apache that removes empty path segments before mapping it. But you can access the original requested URI path via *THE_REQUEST*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /r/([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^r/ /system/offsite/redirect/index.php?url=%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use php [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function

**EDIT:**

```
//echo your url
echo 'http://localhost/r/'. urlencode('http://google.com');
```

and in your index.php file

```
//get your url
$url = urldecode($GET['url']);
```

Comment: I've tried that, this is with urlencode() `http%3A%2Fgoogle.com`. It might be the rewrite rule.

Comment: @NoobiCake: That's as it should be. Decode it in `redirect.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I think REQUEST_URI variable will have correct text. Use it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/r/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^r/ /system/offsite/redirect/index.php?url=%1 [L,QSA,NC]
```