# mod rewrite everything after domain into get

Tags: php, http, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite everything after the domain name into get if it is not already get?

For example : example.com/blah/blah.blah

will become example.com/?blah/blah.blah

basically all I want to do is add a ? after the first forward slash if there isnt one already.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi this is Marty, stackoverflow is not allowing me to edit anymore, but I want to say that zerkms's answer works, however it does not work when there is a forward slash present in the URL (it screws up the directory of the current location). anubhava's solution is not working at all for me. It screws up the current location right away. The only other rewrite I have on is to rewrite files to hide the .php extension. How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by **screws up the current location**. It would be better if you provide more details like what is not working by adding comments rather that opening an exact duplicate question. btw @zerkms and my answer were pretty much on same lines except an anomaly in using `$0` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Comment: I could not add a comment that is the problem, I do not have an account here and apparently the cookie I had set for the guest account deleted. My problem is that when I use your solution with a combination of the rewrite rule that adds .php to files without an extension it does not work. When I load the site, the CSS style sheet does not load, so I am assuming something with the paths gets messed up.

Comment: You should have mentioned about your existing .htaccess rules in this question itself. We (I and @zerkms) spent significant time discussing merits and demerits of the answer to your problem posted here. btw I saw your other question as well. Why would you append `.php` in URI if all you want is to forward to `/index.php`? Inside your index.php you can check whether original URI has `.php` in the end or not. So I would suggest keeping just the code from my answer in your .htaccess file and see how it behaves.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know the solution would interfere with my other rewrite rule. I am appending the .php so it would not be needed for ajax requests. Can you help out with the problem where adding a slash corrupts the location to includes.

Comment: Its kinda difficult for me to build the custom answer for you without knowing your intent and complete setup. Many things you're trying to do many not be needed at all. My suggestion was that if you're forwarding **EVERYTHING** to `/index.php`anyway then there is absolutely no need to append `.php` in URI (it doesn't matter if it is from JAX). So I would suggest again keeping just the code from my answer in your .htaccess file and see how it behaves.

Comment: btw I edited my answer after reading your comments so pls try and let me know.

Comment: It does matter because I am not requesting index.php through ajax but different files.

Comment: I tried your updated code, it works only when there is no slashes after the domain. So if I do `http://www.example.com/test/` it will corrupt index.php setting the path to a different location so includes do not work properly.

Comment: So the slashes do get sent as a query string but for some reason the main directory location of index.php changes...

Comment: I managed to fix the include problem however ajax requests do not work if I request files other than index.php, how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide some more info like: What is the original URI ofr your AJAX call that is not working? As per my rule if request is for `/foo/bar?a=1` above code will make it `/index.php?/foo/bar&a=1`. However this rule is little restrictive because of this condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` this rule will execute **only** when original request filename (eg: `/foo/bar`) doesn't exist on your host. This is to prevent your static files like js, css,images etc getting forwarded to `/index.php`.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /index.php?$0 [QSA]
```

But this solution has some issues, @anubhava's is better ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply use variable `%{REQUEST_URI}` as a query parameter:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It will expectedly cause infinity loop

Comment: This is NOT complete code of .htaccess file, just the answer of OP how to pass original URI as query parameter. I would always suggest having something like `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` before this line to safeguard against looping.

Comment: @zerkms I thought I should just complete it, pls check now.

Comment: so which one is better? this answer or zerkm's? they both look different

Comment: @anubhava: that depends on what OP wants. If he wants to redirect also "asd.ext?a=b" to "/?asd.ext&a=b" - you'll not be able to handle it

Comment: @Marty: my solution is much flexible and semantically more correct

Comment: @zerkms `semantically more correct` would you pls care to elaborate.

Comment: @anubhava: you're relying on the data that is not related to the question - to the existence of query string. It is incorrect based on the question: "How can I rewrite **everything** after the domain name into get if it is not already get". You cannot fit the bolded part.

Comment: @zerkms: In your answer with this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` you're assuming that OP doesn't want to forward `foo.php` to `index.php` if he already has a file `foo.php` which is no where in original question.

Comment: @anubhava: yep, and I easily can fix it with checking if the request doesn't contain index.php, but you cannot fix your issue ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Please spare a min to test your rule :)

Comment: @zerkms: For a URI of `/foo?a=1` your rule makes it `/index.php?foo` thus eats out `a=1` of query string of original request.

Comment: @anubhava: yes, and the fix took 5 keystrokes. Now your turn. Make your rules being able to handle the same case?

Comment: Marty: I would simply suggest you test both versions of rules and whichever works for you in all the conditions just use it.

Comment: @zerkms: My rule is already working fine, nothing to fix at all. For a URI of /foo?a=1 your rule makes it /index.php?foo thus eats out `a=1`. But my code above makes it: `/index.php?/foo&a=1` thus preserving both original URI and query string.

Comment: @anubhava: nope, it doesn't eat it. And yes, your **current** rule is much better.

Comment: @zerkms: I can see you have added `[QSA]` in your most recent edit and that makes it NOT to eat original query string.

Comment: @anubhava: dude, you changed your rule 2 times during our conversation. Read all the comments again, I said 15 minutes ago that: **my original rule is easy to fix, and impossible to fix your original rule**. Is it enough direct to you? Your initial rule was not good enough, but current is - so I even +1'd you.

Comment: No no, pls don't get my wrong, change it as many times to make it work, I do the same when I realize some typo or my mistake  :)

Comment: @zerkms: It was a pleasure to talk to as well and and even I **upvoted** your answer however I would still not suggest `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition since it is very restrictive.

Comment: @anubhava: yep, probably I was totally wrong about semantics :-( Sorry. Anyway, the solution will depends on OP specific requirements.

Comment: Absolutely no problem mate :)

Comment: @zerkms: Sorry to bug you again but there is another issue with using `$0`. Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003028/get-url-from-url-http-google-com So essentially if URI is `/foo/http://abc.com` then `$0` will make it `/foo/http:/abc.com` converting `//` to `/` but with `%{REQUEST_URI}` it remains `/foo/http://abc.com`

Answer (score 1):

Another technique is to use the $_GLOBALS['PATH_INFO'] variable which will give you the rest of the path after the script name, so for:

```
http://example.com/somefile.php/james/fred/blogs.csv?something=value
```

PATH_INFO would be set to "/james/fred/blogs.csv" and you would still have the possibility of using GET/POST variables separately as modifiers.  This can be quite useful, for example if you want to create a .csv file and have it appear to the remote browser client as if it were named "blogs.csv".