# mod rewrite rule to convert everything after domain to a get query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help with rewrite rules in htaccess files. I want everything after the domain, after the first slash to be rewritten to get the query string.

If you take a look at [mod rewrite everything after domain into get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039322/mod-rewrite-everything-after-domain-into-get)

this is pretty much what I want except that I believe that one of my rules (rewrites files to have a php extension) is interfering with the linked solution.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

What can I do to integrate the linked solution with this rewrite as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod rewrite everything after domain into get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039322/mod-rewrite-everything-after-domain-into-get)

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

English version: If the file or directory does not exist, rewrite to index.php with the query string in $_GET['query'].

For greater flexibility, you could also not pass the request uri into GET with htaccess and just read it directly from $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Comment: If I add a slash is messes up the main location of the site so no JS, or CSS is loaded... so it is not putting the slashes into a query string

Comment: It should work, I tried it prior to posting that code. Assuming the directory or file does not exist, it will rewrite everything to index.php; perhaps something bodes ill with the PHP side of things?